# Nagios - adding spaces/tabs/newline Between arguments of Service Check Command

Tags: nagios

For more readability I would like to add spaces around the arguments in a service's check command. Running a nagios check outputs an error as it seems to want everything on one likeso:

[One line check_command definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdlm6.png)

However I would like to spcify the check command likeso:
[separate lines check command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xB3J.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome. Please see this post to edit a question for the community to answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible. Nagios parses configuration attributes by the logic “attribute value \n” so that’s how it has to look.

Other options include breaking it up into multiple check commands, thereby reducing the amount of macros. It’s hard to say since you don’t share the actual text.

On that note, do not share text in pictures. Ever. For any reason. Copy the text and format it as monospaced. If it contains sensitive information, redact it from the text, don’t draw on a picture. Sharing text as pictures is a great way to become very unpopular with colleagues, support personell, and anyone else you come in contact with who has to be able to access the actual text itself, or just want to be able to read it (they may use a screen reader).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding your note, would you say that writing redacted versus crossing out text is just a personal preference? I personally don't see anything wrong with it, albeit it may be unsightly to see

Comment: It’s not really a personal preference because in one case it’s text and in one case it’s not, it’s a picture. Text should be shared as text, because otherwise it can’t be searched, handled, or otherwise parsed in the many ways text should be able to be. People with degraded sight using screen readers is just one example, but searchability is another (for example making the text findable from google)